# Twitter bootstrap issue using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Can anybody please solve me one issue regarding bootstrap using in ROR.

## Issue:

I have integrated gem "'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'" in my gem file.After adding some bootstrap navigation code in application.html.erb,it is showing one nice bootstrap navigation bar.If i am doing some changes in style sheet and refreshes the page it is splitting means the nav menu lists is not coming in inline and next time onward it is repeating.Actually i want the original nav bootstrap bar even if I did any changes in style sheet.

Please check my below code snippets and make it correct.

My codes are as follows:

## Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'
```

## homes.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

## application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LibraryManagement</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "Library Management System", '#', id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Home",   '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Books",   '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Member Entry", '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Admin Login", '#' %></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## homes/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Index page</h1>
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some tips: 1) The `Gemfile` isn't relevant here, so you can take it out of your question. 2) The `application.css.scss` *is* relevant, so please add it.

Comment: Are you trying to build a Rails4 app from scratch with bootstrap3 ? If yes, please try (https://github.com/Jrakesh/rails4-kickoff) or [RailsApps](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise). I got help from these.